# How to set primary key in datatable in f#?

Tags: database, f#

Like in C#

```
objDataTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { objDataTable.Columns["Student Id"] };
```

How to do it in F# ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.[ ... ] access array element

[| ... |] create array

<- assign value to variable

```
objDataTable.PrimaryKey <- [| objDataTable.Columns.["Student Id"] |]
```